# Gradle Project sync failed. Android Studio 3.1.3

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-3.1, android-studio-3.1.3

100% new to android. Installed it and was trying to run the basic hello world program from the tutorial https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/creating-project.

However when I go to activity_mail.xml and then to the design view, it doesn't allow me to see it and it says "design editor not available until a sucesful build".

It also says "Cause: unable to find valid certification path to requested target"

Here are some screenshots. It also says something about dependencies stuff

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yTr5s.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/otTcm.png)

I have seen somehow similar questions, but the answers don't apply to my case. Also here are my versions: MAC OS X El capitan
Android Studio 3.1.3 . May all this have something to do with the version of Android Studio I'm using?

Comment: close layout windows then rebuild project from build menu

Comment: @WIZARD what do you mean layout windows?

Comment: Have you installed Android SDK?

Comment: @shizhen pretty sure I have. Is there a way to double check?

Comment: Check your local.properties file under your project root directory, your Android SDK should have been properly configured

Comment: @shizhen I just checked the file. How do I know if Android DKS is properly configured?

Comment: @dev74 i meant any open android studio tab that contains layout

Answer (score 0):

you can add this to your gradle

and it will work

```
build gradle(project): maven {
        url "https://maven.google.com"
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Which gradle? There are many gradle files